# Are the eigenvalues of a matrix related to the eigenvalues of its symmetric and antisymmetric parts?:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose we have a real matrix $A$ with symmetric antisymmetric parts given by $A_s = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$ and $A_a = \frac{1}{2}(A-A^T)$ so that $A = A_s + A_a$. These satisfy $A_s = A_s^T$ and $A_a = -A^T$.

$A_s$ will always have real eigenvalues, $A_a$ will have purely imaginary eigenvalues and $A$, in general, will have complex eigenvalues.

If $A_a$ and $A_s$ share an eigenvector, then this is also an eigenvector of $A$ with eigevalue equal to the sum of the two eigenvalues. However, I am wondering if there is any  more general relation between the eigenvalues of $A_s$, $A_a$ and $A$, which does not rely on this assumption.

I know that in general, relating the eigenvalues of individual matrices to the eigenvalues of their sum is a difficult problem, so am aware the answer may just be 'no'.

However, when playing around with $2\times2$ matrices numerically, I noticed that making the antisymmetric part larger decreased the difference between the real parts of the largest and smallest eigenvalues. I was wondering: is there was a way to quantify this? Is this a general pattern for $n\times n$ matrices?

Thanks in advance.